# My question is about raise NotFittedError("Must fit neighbors before querying.")

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, knn

I am writting a code to analyse stock prices through tutorials. I am stuck in one or two lines of code where error is showing as:"NotFittedError: Must fit neighbors before querying." and one more error is:"clf is not defined".

i've tried fitting neighbors and defining clf.

Please check the url provided for the whole code:"https://towardsdatascience.com/in-12-minutes-stocks-analysis-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-a8d8a7b50ee7"

```
#Evaluation
confidencereg = clfreg.score(X_test, y_test)
confidencepoly2 = clfpoly2.score(X_test,y_test)
confidencepoly3 = clfpoly3.score(X_test,y_test)
confidenceknn = clfknn.score(X_test, y_test)

#For sanity testing, let us print some of the stocks forecast.
forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
dfreg['Forecast'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the case that the tutorial you're following somewhere defined a model named `clf` (which is normal), which you haven't declared and therefore couldn't have fitted.

It's very difficult to give further advice or insights without a little more context. I suggest you improve your question by mentioning which tutorial you're following, how you're replicating it, and the full error stack.

Comment: i am giving you the link

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/in-12-minutes-stocks-analysis-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-a8d8a7b50ee7

Comment: here you will find all the code lines. I have mentioned the code of lines whee i am facing the error. These line of codes are 137-145